# How to override Nested div in list

Tags: html, css

I have a situation here which I could not resolve.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
#midcol ul {
padding-left: 25px;
}
.mylist ul {
padding-left: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="midcol">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="mylist">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I override the padding style of midcol to my lists of class mylist? It's currently taking the style of midcol and is ignoring the style defined for mylist.

Answer (score 1):

You can change:

```
#midcol ul {
padding-left: 25px;
}
```

to:

```
#midcol > ul {
padding-left: 25px;
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Nest the styles:

```
#midcol .mylist ul {
padding-left: 5px;
}
```